# How many points on a sphere whose distance is greater than $\epsilon$

Tags: information-theory, spheres

I have a "simple" question, but my first researches are not very successful. Given a dimension $d$ and a distance $\epsilon$, is there a standard lower bound on the number of points $N(d,\epsilon)$ that we can fit on the unit sphere $S_{d-1}$?

Comment: These are standard problems that can become quite difficult. The keywords to search for are "spherical code" and "kissing problem"

Comment: [This page on spherical codes](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCode.html) can be useful